# how to export my sql table to a .doc file using php and download it

Tags: php, pdf-generation, doc, auto-generate

I have a table with large amount of data in my sql database, i have to take a copy of .doc or .pdf format using PHP coding.

I have to download while clicking the Download Button in my Page.

In my table i have Student details with the following format

[image]

And i tried to Get in the Form of

[image]

But i'm getting the value with out Tabular form and S.no in the .Doc file

My Code in my Php File is,..

```
<?php
include "../../db_connection/db_connection.php";
include "../../config/config.php";  
 ?>
<?PHP
 $result =mysql_query("SELECT Stu_id,Name,Class,Total,Rank FROM Student");
 $i = 0;
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++)
    echo mysql_field_name($result, $i)." ";
print("\n\n\n");
    }
  $values = mysql_query("SELECT Stu_id,Name,Class,Total,Rank  FROM Student");
  while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
     for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
        $csv_output .= $rowr[$j]." ";
      }
     $csv_output .= "\n\n";
    }
    $filename = "Result"."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".docx");
    header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".docx");
    print $csv_output;
    exit;
  ?>
```

My Output for this code is,..

[image]

Here where can i add the values to get S.No and how to form the Tabular form in the .Doc type..

Can i use the same code for generating PDF file for the Same Process?

Anybody suggest Best idea..!

Comment: Look into: [PHP PDF Module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdf.php)

Comment: Or use a library, I personally liked this one: http://www.fpdf.org/ Just google search for it.

Comment: You can use TCPDF library to generate the PDF using PHP. It is a great library.

Comment: The only DOC & PDF system I know of that you can reach from PHP using the same code is the web service called Docmosis.  It lets you create tables.  Please note I work for the company.